# Is it possible to use phonegap nfc plugin by chariot solutions to make an android device act as passive(tag)

Tags: android, cordova, nfc

Is it possible to use phonegap nfc plugin by chariot solutions to make an android device act as passive(tag)? I want to test the plugin on an android device(galaxy s4) but do not have any tag. So can i use one device to act as a tag and read it using the other device?

Comment: Emulating a tag isn't supported by Android by default, so using a wrapper (eg. phonegap) will not overcome this. The only thing that will give you similar ux is using beam api. Not totally sure about this information..

Comment: You won't be able to reliably emulate a tag. Best thing is to get hold of a real one. For only a few cents you can get quite sophisticated chips, e.g. mifare ultralight C in stickers. Real world testing is what you need. Btw, the chariot solutions NFC plugin works fine for this - I have used it in a couple of Phonegap-based apps :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not use use it for this purpose but if you want to share some data between phone and an NFC enabled device (phone/usb nfc pad) you may use the p2p sample here (https://github.com/don/phonegap-p2p/).

```
var record = ndef.uriRecord("http://www.kazi.net");
nfc.share(
              [record], 
              function(){ alert ("Successful")},
              function(){ alert ("Failed")}
          );
```